# Can I somehow create 1 annotation to replace another with default values?

Tags: java, annotations

I fear title is bad, but could not formulate it better. So, I have this code:

`@javax.interceptor.Interceptors({EjbSecurityServerInterceptor.class,PermissionInterceptor.class})`

Is there a way to create annotation like `@SecuredAsHell`, that will be an equivalent to aforementioned annotation? Smth like macros, I suppose.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Sorry, but the fact is that whatever reflection that is used to locate annotations of type  javax.interceptor.Interceptors will only locate annotations of that type. There is not way to indicate that another annotation is somehow equivalent.

Comment: Cannot experiment now, but what if I create a child of `@javax.interceptor.Interceptors`?

Comment: @popfalushi Annotations cannot be extended, though I can't recall the rationale why